# How do I tell CPAN.pm to use an application-specific mini-cpan?

Tags: perl, cpan, minicpan

Is there a way to use app-specific mini-CPANs (to ensure specific module versions for different apps and make an install work without net access). The 'standard' mini-cpan way of things relies on setting 'o conf urllist' with a file url in your CPAN/Config.pm

That's fine with one single mini-cpan. However, I need to automate having a CPAN install from a different directory for each app (local to the app), as each app has different version requirements.

The following *almost* works, but then has only a partially working shell, and still fetches from the web instead of using the mini-cpan from `$file_url` location:

```
use CPAN;
use FindBin qw($Bin);

my $file_url="file:///$Bin/../cpan";
CPAN::Shell->o(qw( conf urllist ),$file_url);

CPAN::shell();
```

Comment: Could you use PAR::Packer to package your perl app instead?

Comment: PAR::Packer is a useful solution for distributing to the same operating system, but doesn't solve the problem of versioning local copies of CPAN modules and install to a different operating system (which I should have mentioned is needed, sorry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You load a different configuration file for each application. The latest [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Cpan) command has a `-j` switch to do just that:

```
$ cpan -j some/app/Config.pm -i Foo::Bar
```

This latest feature isn't included in the [CPAN.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN) distribution yet since it's experimental. I've been using it for several months, however, as part of my [DPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MyCPAN-App-DPAN) work.

If you don't like any of that, you just have to provide your application-specific `CPAN::Config` module somewhere Perl will find it before it finds your personal or site-wide version. Copy your current *CPAN/Config.pm* into your application modules directory and ensure that the directory is first in @INC (perhaps using the `PERL5LIB` environment variable). CPAN.pm should find that one first and use it. It only uses the first one it finds. This is handy when the configuration is fixed, although it's a bit flexible since you can run code in the module. It's configuration as Perl code.

If that is not good enough for you, you can override `CPAN::HandleConfig()` in your application so  CPAN.pm doesn't load any files. You then set the values yourself. This is especially handy when you have a lot of application logic to resolve to figure out some of the configurations values. The CPAN.pm configuration is just the `%CPAN::Config` hash, so you just have to set the right values for the appropriate keys.

In any case, you probably want to set the "connect_to_internet_ok" configuration to a false value and clean out your "urllist" to have only the local minicpans.